# Authenticated failed registration error c2dm

Tags: android

In c2dm registration error authenticated failed.what is the reson.when we run on the HTC      desire work properly.when we run on the samsung galaxy ace.then it shows the Log cat  authenticated failed in registration error.Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when these type of error then resetfactory of the android phone.it will be work.